# Continuity of the function equal to the sum of terms $x/(x^2+n^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am being asked to prove that the following function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$:

$$F(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+n^2}$$

However, I am somewhat stumped. Weierstrass' M-test, which would be the most natural way for me to prove uniform convergence of the series and thereby continuity (as $f_n$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$), does not work: by, for each function, choosing $x=n$ it is seen that

$$f_n(n)=\frac{n}{n^2+n^2}=\frac{1}{2n}$$
whereby the summants of any majorant series would have to be at least of size $\frac{1}{2n}$ or greater, which is just half of the harmonic series. Therefore there cannot exist a convergent majorant series, so the $M$-test is not applicable.

I've instead been trying to prove this directly from the definition, that is proving that

$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\,\exists n\in\mathbb{N},\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: n\geq N\Rightarrow \left|\sum_{j=n}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+j^2} \right|<\varepsilon$$
but these efforts have been fruitless - it is very easy to prove pointwise convergence, but to find an $N$ that "works" for all $x$ still eludes me. Please assist me.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3960266/42969 – the functions differ only by a factor $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a>0$ and consider the restriction of $F$ to $(-a,a)$. Here, if you try to apply the Weierstrass $M$-test, you get$$\sup_{x\in(-a,a)}\left|\frac x{x^2+n^2}\right|\leqslant\frac a{n^2}$$and so, since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac a{n^2}$ converges, $F|_{(-a,a)}$ is continuous, due to uniform convergence. Since this occurs for each $a>0$, $F$ is continuous.