# Continuity of $f(x) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find if $f(x) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}$ is continuous.
I don't really know how to proceed since it doesn't have uniform convergence and therefore I can't use the theorem to transfer the continuity.

Comment: Hint:  $f(x) = 2x \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3960266/42969 for an almost identical problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for $x\in [-R,R]$,
$$
\left|\frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}\right|=\frac{2|x|}{x^2+n^2}\leq \frac{2R}{n^2}
$$
which is summable.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=2xg(x)$ where $g(x)$ is the continuous function resulting from the uniformly convergent series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+k^2}$.

For the record, the original series converges uniformly on compact subsets.